# find a group of records based on oracle query

Tags: oracle

I have 3 tables and need to write a query:
based on the request_id in the member table, I need to do the following: for each members find which group he belongs to and display the group_type and all users belong to that group. So for member mike@yahoo.com, he belongs to group A and there are 2 users belong to that group (mike@yahoo.com and sam@yahoo.com). We need to display both. For member peter@yahoo.com, he belongs to group B and there are no other ones belong to that group. We just display 1 record

--- the users table is used to link the members with the groups tables.
users, members, groups

```
users tble
----------
user_id    email
1          mike@yahoo.com
2          sam@yahoo.com
3          peter@yahoo.com

create table users_tbl (id number, email varchar2);

insert into users_tbl values(1, 'mike@yahoo.com');
insert into users_tbl values(2, 'sam@yahoo.com');
insert into users_tbl values(3, 'peter@yahoo.com');


members tble
------------
member_id    request_id  email
1               123      mike@yahoo.com
2               123      peter@yahoo.com   

create table members_tbl (member_id number, request_id number, email varchar2);

insert into members_tbl values(1, 123, 'mike@yahoo.com');
insert into members_tbl values(2, 123, 'peter@yahoo.com');

groups table
------------
group_id      group_type    user_id     
  1                A          1
  2                A          2 
  3                B          3

create table groups_tbl (group_id number, group_type varchar2, user_id number);

insert into groups_tbl values (1, 'A', 1);  
insert into groups_tbl values (2, 'A', 2);  
insert into groups_tbl values (3, 'B', 3);  


    
so the final result based on the data should look like this:

group_type  email
--------    ------ 
A           mike@yahoo.com
A           sam@yahoo.com
B           peter@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple join between `users_tbl` and `groups_tbl` should do the job:

```
select group_type, email
from users_tbl u inner join groups_tbl g
on u.id = g.user_id
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc177/2)

Comment: We must use the member table as it will be the driving force to get the records based on the request_id.

Comment: @IceTea I don't see how it's needed in the example you gave. Maybe add a few rows to showcase a scenario where members_tbl would be needed in the final result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure...
May be like this:

```
select g1.group_type, u1.email 
from 
 (select distinct g.group_type  
        from members_tbl m,
             users_tbl u,
             groups g  
     where m.request_id = 123    
       and m.email = u.email   
       and u.group_id = g.group_id) x,  
      users u1, 
     groups g1 
    where g1.group_type = x.group_type   
      and g1.user_id = u1.user_id
```

or, if you want to output results for ALL requests in members_tbl, just comment first predicate:

```
select g1.group_type, u1.email 
    from 
     (select distinct g.group_type  
            from members_tbl m,
                 users_tbl u,
                 groups g  
         where /*m.request_id = 123    
           and*/ m.email = u.email   
           and u.group_id = g.group_id) x,  
          users u1, 
         groups g1 
        where g1.group_type = x.group_type   
          and g1.user_id = u1.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select b.group_type,a.email from users a,groups b
where a.user_id = b.user_id
and b.group_type in (select b.group_type from members x,groups y, users z
where z.user_id = y.user_id and z.email = x.email and x.request_id = 123)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?